# Referencing a SESSION() in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to reference a variable stored in a `SESSION()` from a `SESSION()` controller and I'm having a bit of trouble with the code.  What I have are two tables, one for articles and one for  authors. The author id of the current user logged in is stored in my `$id` variable via a SQL query in access.inc.php in `function databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password, &$id)`, then referenced in `function userIsLoggedIn() and stored in $_SESSION['id']`

**includes>access.inc.php**

```
<?php
function userIsLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login')
    {
        if (!isset($_POST['email']) or $_POST['email'] == '' or
            !isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] == '')
        {
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Please fill in both fields';
            return FALSE;
        }
        $password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'chainfire db');

        if (databaseContainsAuthor($_POST['email'], $password, $id))
        {   
        include 'db.inc.php';
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];  
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            session_start();
            unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']);
            unset($_SESSION['password']);
            unset($_SESSION['id']);
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'The specified email address or password was incorrect.';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
    {
        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        unset($_SESSION['id']);
        header('Location: ' . $_POST['goto']);
        exit();
    }
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
    {
        return databaseContainsAuthor($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['id']);
    }
}
function databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password, &$id)
{
    include 'db.inc.php';

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author
            WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (!$result)
    {
        $error = 'Error searching for author.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM author 
            WHERE email='$email'"; 
    $id = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!$id)
    {
        $error = 'Error searching for id.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }    

    if ($row[0] > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now that I have the variable `$id`, which contains the current user's id, stored in `$_SESSION['id']`, I would like to use the `SESSION()` in a SQL query in my index.php to insert the author's id along with their articles in my article table so the author and the article the author submits are linked.  I'm just having a bit of trouble implementing the correct code to reference `$_SESSION['id']` in my SQL query for index.php

**articles>index.php**

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
        '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
        '/includes/access.inc.php';

if (isset($_GET['add']))
  if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
      include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/login.inc.html.php';
      exit();
}
  else
{
    $pagetitle = 'New Article';
    $action = 'addform';
    $text = '';
    $authorid = '';
    $id = '';
    $button = 'Add article';

    include 'form.html.php';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['text']);
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO article SET
            articletext='$text',
            articledate=CURDATE(),
            authorid= '$id'";
    if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error adding submitted article: ' . mysqli_error($link);
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, articletext FROM article');
if (!$result)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching articles: ' . mysqli_error($link);
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $articles[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['articletext']);
}

include 'articles.html.php';
?>
```

The `SESSION()` I'm trying to reference is under `if (isset($_GET['addform']))`, but I;m unsure if this is the rite syntax to use to do so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script, then edit your question & include that error...

Comment: Lawrence - There doesn't seem to be an error when I add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, so I suspect the syntax is correct, the problem is when an article is submitted, the authorid column in my article table returns 0 when it should, if the code is correct, return the id of the author who submitted the article.

Comment: you should look into that OOP thing .. might learn something

Comment: Last time I checked, Session information is stored on the server which is strictly a php thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems fine.Check if $id has the value you expect it to be just before the query because if it is returning zero every time your authorid must have some default value which always show up,zero in this case.